# Is the given matrix unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a matrix having blocks of unitary matrices along the main diagonal  eg.
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\
                     0 & D\end{pmatrix}$$
Here $A$ and $D$ are  $3$x$3$ and  $2$x$2$ unitary matrices repsectively.
Are matrices of type $M$, having block unitary matrices ( of different sizes ) along the main diagonal unitary in general ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $$\left (\begin{matrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{matrix} \right )\left (\begin{matrix}C & 0 \\ 0 & D\end{matrix} \right )=\left (\begin{matrix}AC & 0 \\ 0 & BD\end{matrix} \right )$$

If the blocks $A$ and $C$ have the same size, and the blocks $B$ and $D$ have the same size.

Use this, the fact that the blocks are unitary, and that $\left (\begin{matrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{matrix} \right )^\ast = \left (\begin{matrix}A^\ast & 0 \\ 0 & B^\ast\end{matrix} \right )$ to show that $$\left (\begin{matrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{matrix} \right )\left (\begin{matrix}A^\ast & 0 \\ 0 & B^\ast\end{matrix} \right )=\left (\begin{matrix}A^\ast & 0 \\ 0 & B^\ast\end{matrix} \right )\left (\begin{matrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{matrix} \right )=I$$

Comment: Is it only true same block sizes then ?

Comment: Not all the blocks have to have the same size; the upper blocks can have a different (common) size than the lower blocks.

Comment: @BrianTung I mean can $A$ and $C$ have different sizes ?

Comment: If they do, then the first equation provided by Reveillark is not true.  But in the problem you ask, they are the same size, since $C$ is just $A^*$.

Comment: @Reveillark thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

With $T$ representing the appropriate transpose for your field:

$$(Mx)^T Mx = x^T M^TM x = x^T \begin{pmatrix} A^T & 0 \\ 0 & D^T\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & D\end{pmatrix} x = x^T\begin{pmatrix} A^TA & 0 \\ 0 & D^TD \end{pmatrix}x.$$

Write $x = \begin{pmatrix} x_A \\ x_D\end{pmatrix}$ and note that since $A, D$ are unitary, $x_A^T A^TA x_A = x_A^T x_A$ and $x_D^T D^TDx_D = x_D^T x_D$.

Then,

$$x^T\begin{pmatrix} A^TA & 0 \\ 0 & D^TD \end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix} x_A^t & x_D^T\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A^TA & 0 \\ 0 & D^TD \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_A \\ x_D\end{pmatrix} = x_A^Tx_A + x_D^Tx_D = x^Tx.$$

Comment: @Aramis is it true in general for matrices have unitary block matrices along main diagonal with different sizes ?

Comment: @sasha Think a little on this and you should be able to answer that question for yourself.

Comment: got it thanks :)